# Xcode IB's Contraint properties 'wC' & 'hR'?

Tags: xcode, xcode6

What do the 'wC' & 'hR' mean the contracts properties?

I assume it has something to with height & width, respectively.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Someone added a size class customization by pressing the little `+` button in front of Constant.

What you see is the constant which was set for `Width: Compact Height: Regular`. This constant will be used on all current iPhones in Portrait Mode. The not customized constant, 30, will be used if the device the app is running on is not an iPhone in Portrait Mode. I.e. all iPads (they are wRhR regardless of orientation), or iPhones in Landscape mode (6 Plus: wRhC, others: wChC).

Since -14 means the view will above the top layout guide this might have happened accidentally. In this case you can remove the custom constant by pressing the `x` in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

`wC hC` means **C**ompact **w**idth, **C**ompact **h**eight.

- w = width
- h = height
- C = Compact
- R = Regular

In Xcode, there is a `Vary for Traits` button which allows you to customize layout for certain screen sizes. This functionality is known as **size classes.**